# Set new data in dynamic spinner at specific position based on any spinner item selection

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am making an application where i have product detail screen , In that screen i am creating dynamic spinners based on the length of configurable items.Every thing is working fine , but when i try to change the list of other dynamic spinners based on selection of first Dynamic spinner item , the filtered array get shifted to clicked spinner list but it should be added to another spinner not the same i clicked.Please help me in this i am really stuck at this situation, i tried a lot but not able to implement, So i am seeking your help in this .

**Scenario is** Suppose **for specific product i have 2 spinners one is for Color attribute and other is for Size attribute** And both are interlinked with each other For Example :-

Under Color spinner i have three colors :- White , Blue , Green
Similarly Under Size i have :- S,M,L,XL

**But for white color i am having only two sizes available i.e S and M**
So what i need is when user click on Spinner with color attribute White , the array in Second spinner automatically get changed to S,M and viseversa

I am doing all these in dynamic spinner.

Here is my code :-

```
private void showconfigurableProducts() {
            try {
                    count = 0;
                    mllSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    for (int i = 0; i < lisProductDetail.get(0).getConfigurable()
                                    .size(); i++) {
                            TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
                            tv.setText(lisProductDetail.get(0).getConfigurable().get(i)
                                            .getLabel());
                            mllSpinner.addView(tv);
                            final Spinner spinner = new Spinner(getActivity());
                            spinner.setTag(i);
                            final ArrayAdapter<OptionProductDetailModel> arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<OptionProductDetailModel>(
                                            getActivity(),
                                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                                            lisProductDetail.get(0).getConfigurable().get(i)
                                                            .getOptions());
                            spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                            spinner.setSelection(0, false);
                            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                                    private String attributeId;

                                    @Override
                                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                                    View view, int position, long id) {
                                            OptionProductDetailModel option = (OptionProductDetailModel) spinner
                                                            .getSelectedItem();
                                            List<OptionProductDetailModel> sizedataArray = new ArrayList<OptionProductDetailModel>();
                                            sizedataArray.add(option);
                                            if (listDummy.size() > 0) {
                                                    selectbtatrue = check(sizedataArray, listDummy);
                                            }

                                            if (selectbtatrue) {
                                                    return;
                                            } else {

                                                    for (int i = 0; i < lisProductDetail.get(0)
                                                                    .getConfigurable().size(); i++) {
                                                            for (int j = 0; j < lisProductDetail.get(0)
                                                                            .getConfigurable().get(i).getOptions()
                                                                            .size(); j++) {
                                                                    if (lisProductDetail.get(0)
                                                                                    .getConfigurable().get(i)
                                                                                    .getOptions().get(j).getLabel() == option
                                                                                    .getLabel()) {
                                                                            attributeId = lisProductDetail.get(0)
                                                                                            .getConfigurable().get(i)
                                                                                            .getId();
                                                                    }
                                                            }
                                                    }
                                                    for (int i = 0; i < lisProductDetail.get(0)
                                                                    .getConfigurable().size(); i++) {
                                                            if (attributeId != lisProductDetail.get(0)
                                                                            .getConfigurable().get(i).getId()) {
                                                                    // if (listDummy.size() > 0) {
                                                                    // listDummy = new
                                                                    // ArrayList<OptionProductDetailModel>();
                                                                    // }
                                                                    for (int k = 0; k < option.getProducts()
                                                                                    .size(); k++) {
                                                                            for (int j = 0; j < lisProductDetail
                                                                                            .get(0).getConfigurable()
                                                                                            .get(i).getOptions().size(); j++) {
                                                                                    for (int l = 0; l < lisProductDetail
                                                                                                    .get(0).getConfigurable()
                                                                                                    .get(i).getOptions().get(j)
                                                                                                    .getProducts().size(); l++) {
                                                                                            if (option
                                                                                                            .getProducts()
                                                                                                            .get(k)
                                                                                                            .equals(lisProductDetail
                                                                                                                            .get(0)
                                                                                                                            .getConfigurable()
                                                                                                                            .get(i)
                                                                                                                            .getOptions()
                                                                                                                            .get(j)
                                                                                                                            .getProducts()
                                                                                                                            .get(l))) {

                                                                                                    listDummy
                                                                                                                    .add(lisProductDetail
                                                                                                                                    .get(0)
                                                                                                                                    .getConfigurable()
                                                                                                                                    .get(i)
                                                                                                                                    .getOptions()
                                                                                                                                    .get(j));
                                                                                            } else {

                                                                                            }
                                                                                    }
                                                                            }
                                                                            System.out.print(listDummy);
                                                                    }

                                                            }
                                                            if (count < 2) {
                                                                    int tag = (int) spinner.getTag();
                                                                    if (tag == i) {

                                                                    } else {
                                                                            lisProductDetail.get(0)
                                                                                            .getConfigurable().get(i)
                                                                                            .setOptions(listDummy);  // Here i am getting S,M,L but  i do not know how to update in in Size Attribute Spinner. 

                                                                    }
                                                                    count = count + 1;
                                                            }
                                                    }
                                            }

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                    }

                            });
                            mllSpinner.addView(spinner);
                    }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }


 private boolean check(List<OptionProductDetailModel> SelectedArray,
            List<OptionProductDetailModel> DummyArray) {
        for (int i = 0; i < SelectedArray.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < DummyArray.size(); j++) {
                if (SelectedArray.get(i).getId()
                        .equalsIgnoreCase(DummyArray.get(j).getId())) {
                    btatrue = true;
                } else {
                    btatrue = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return btatrue;
    }
```

Please provide me your suggestions,Your help will be appreciated
I have been wasted my 2 days on this issue , **Is it feasible or not in case of Dynamic** spinner.
Thank you

Comment: too much complex way to explaining and too much complex code. Please simplify of what you want! :)

Comment: Hey Jimit , i just want to change the spinner list items based on selection of any of the spinner item , condition is all spinners are dynamic

Comment: then try inception method. fill other spinner inside `onItemSelected` method of first `onItemSelected` method, and inside it's `onItemSelected` method the next spinner and so on...!!!

Comment: Please have a look on code above , we are having single object for spinner so there will be only one onItemSelected method , in this case we can set tags to identify that which spinner has been clicked and accordingly which spinners items i need to change .

Answer (score 0):

As Per My understanding creating dynamic spinner is not good idea. You can fill the data according to the item selected on different spinner and if you want to show other spinner once user select any data from first spinner then you can manage the visibility of other spinners. Still if you want to use spinner as dynamic then here is the code:-

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private LinearLayout mContainerLL;
private Spinner mProductSPN;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mContainerLL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_spn_container);
    mProductSPN = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spn_product);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.product));
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mProductSPN.setAdapter(adapter);
    mProductSPN.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            prepareColorSpinner(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}

private void prepareSizeSpinner(int productPosition, int colorPosition) {
    if(mContainerLL.getChildCount()>=3) {
        mContainerLL.removeViewAt(2);
    }
    Spinner sizeSPN = new Spinner(this);
    String[] sizeArray = null;
    switch (productPosition) {
        case 0:
            switch (colorPosition) {
                case 0:
                    sizeArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.size_1);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    sizeArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.size_2);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    sizeArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.size_3);
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            switch (colorPosition) {
                case 0:
                    sizeArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.size_3);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    sizeArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.size_2);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    sizeArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.size_1);
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            switch (colorPosition) {
                case 0:
                    sizeArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.size_2);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    sizeArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.size_1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    sizeArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.size_3);
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, sizeArray);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sizeSPN.setAdapter(adapter);
    mContainerLL.addView(sizeSPN,2);
}

private void prepareColorSpinner(final int productPosition) {
    if(mContainerLL.getChildCount()>=2) {
        mContainerLL.removeViewAt(1);
    }
    Spinner colorSPN = new Spinner(this);
    String[] colorArray = null;
    switch (productPosition) {
        case 0:
            colorArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.color_1);
            break;
        case 1:
            colorArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.color_2);
            break;
        case 2:
            colorArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.color_3);
            break;
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, colorArray);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    colorSPN.setAdapter(adapter);
    mContainerLL.addView(colorSPN,1);
    colorSPN.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            prepareSizeSpinner(productPosition,position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
  }
}
```

strings.xml

```
    <string-array name="product">
    <item>Product 1</item>
    <item>Product 2</item>
    <item>Product 3</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="color_1">
    <item>Red</item>
    <item>Black</item>
    <item>White</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="color_2">
    <item>Green</item>
    <item>Blue</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="color_3">
    <item>Voilet</item>
    <item>Purple</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="size_1">
    <item>Small</item>
    <item>Large</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="size_2">
    <item>Medium</item>
    <item>XLarge</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="size_3">
    <item>Small</item>
    <item>Medium</item>
    <item>Large</item>
</string-array>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.praween.customviews.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_spn_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spn_product"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Change the logic according to your need as I have written the logic on behalf of one scenario you have shared.